# Can't Compile Tesseract API example for WIndows using Tesseract 3.0.2.02 archive

Tags: tesseract

I'm looking at using Tesseract to do some work with PDF files, and so I want to use the library rather than an external executable.

I started by downloading the full Tesseract source and looking at building that. Sadly the standard sources don't have any means to build on a non-Linux platform, in my case Windows. There are methods for doing so, and I looked at those.

Firstly the VS2008 build doesn't. I'm aware that it need Leptonica, but I figured I'd tackle that afterwards and just tried to build the existing code. Fails with "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'allheaders.h': No such file or directory". Nothing to do with Leptonica at this stage, it simply doesn't work.

Even if I were able to get past that, I'd have to build Leptonica, and that requires using GNU tools and therefore an installation of Cygwin, so I gave up. I Have a MingW instatllation, (I've never managed to get Cygwin to work in a usable fashion) but I'm not keen enough to mess with such a complicated and fragile build.

So I decided I'd just use the pre-built binaries which some kind soul creates. Downloaded that from code.google.com. Now I need to look into using the code, so the next obvious step is the Tesseract API example, which states it requires "tesseract-ocr-3.02.02-win32-lib-include-dirs.zip", no problem, because I already have that now.

No real clue as to where the API example wants the files to be placed, but a little messing about gets them in appropriate locations. Press build and "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'allheaders.h': No such file or directory", just like trying to build Tesseract from source.....

And indeed there is no such file.

So, where is this file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also struggled some time ago to make it works under windows and then I found this git repository : https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract-vs2012

It includes all needed extern library (because Tesseract need Leptonica, but Leptonica also need extern library to handle the different image format) and is also working great with vs 2013.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, I did eventually get it working, a kind Leptonica user has also made available pre-built Windows libraries, and with the addition of these in the correct location I was able to build the example code. But  again, thank you for the information.

Answer (score 2):

OK so now I see that allheaders.h is part of Leptonica. Still leaves me wondering why the Tesseract pre-built library requires that I have Leptonica available, I would have expected that to be built-in, I guess it isn't.