# Python Tesserocr with Leptonica Windows 10

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract, leptonica

I'm trying to install tesserocr package in Windows 10.

It gives error as under:

tesseract_ocr.cpp(463) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'leptonica/allheaders.h': No such file or directory

Any solution??

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate. Seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588087/cant-compile-tesseract-api-example-for-windows-using-tesseract-3-0-2-02-archive)?

Comment: Not work this solution